# How to hide figure size when plotting a figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the following function to plot a confusion matrix in Python/matplotlib:

```
def print_conf_mat(y_test, y_pred):
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
classes = ['Normal', 'Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3', 'Type 4', 'Type 5', 'Type 6']
imshow(conf_mat, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.Blues)
print('Confusion matrix:')
colorbar()
tick_marks = arange(len(classes))
xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
yticks(tick_marks, classes)
fmt = 'd'
thresh = conf_mat.max() / 2.
for i, j in product(range(conf_mat.shape[0]), range(conf_mat.shape[1])):
    text(j, i, format(conf_mat[i, j], fmt),
             horizontalalignment="center",
             color="white" if conf_mat[i, j] > thresh else "black")
xlabel('Predicted label')
ylabel('True label')
tight_layout()
figure()
show()
```

I get the matrix in the following format:

[image: Confusion matrix plotted with matplotlib]

I'd like to get rid of the annoying line that says

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Any clues on how I achieve this?

Comment: I can't see any line that says "" in that picture, nor in your code? I'm not quite sure what you're asking

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `figure()`, which is useless anyways?

Comment: Sorry. I uploaded the correct image.

Comment: Removing figure() was the correct solution. Thank you ImportanceOfBeingErnest!

Comment: But when you actually want to do `fig = plt.figure()` and then perhaps something else like `fig.tight_layout()`, that becomes a problem

Answer (score 0):

In other situation here, even without the method`figure()`I got the same boring dimensions.

Workaround: adding `plt.show()` as you can see:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,10))
ax[0].imshow(RGB_image)
ax[0].set_title('RGB image')
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[1].imshow(L,cmap='gray' )
ax[1].set_title('L channel (Lightness)')
ax[1].axis('off')

plt.show()
```